# Docker-machine error in Linux

Tags: docker, centos, docker-machine

[image: docker-machine error]

I want to create `docker-machine` device in `CentOs`

But when i create docker-machine it has message that Error with pre-create check:

```
"VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"
```

What should i do??

Comment: `apt-get install virtualbox` and check that kvm module is in your CentOS kernel (if virtualbox works, it's ok, else you have to install a new version of the kernel with this module enabled).

Comment: How to check kvm module?

Comment: For the kvm modules, try to launch your docker-machine. If it doesn't work, use `virtualbox --version` or `VBoxManage --version`, they are supposed to tell that there is a problem with the kvm module if there is a problem. It often happens on servers rented by server-providers, by default the virtualization modules are disabled.

Comment: When i insert docker-machine version command
it's print
docker-machine version 0.10.0, build 76ed2a6

I think kvm module is OK

Answer (score 0):

In my case docker-machine was installed under /snap/bin/ and also in /usr/bin.
The one being used was from /snap/bin and was not working. 
I explicitly invoked /usr/bin/docker-machine -d virtualbox default and that worked.